# PyQt5: How to move a QObject to the main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, qt5, pyqt5

I know that in general, `QObject()` instances should be created in the main thread. I also know that - once created - you can move a `QObject()` from the main thread to another one:

official Qt docs can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)

```
    # Worker-object approach
    # -----------------------
    # Note: these codelines execute in the main thread.
    workerThread = QThread()
    workerObj = WorkerObj()
    workerObj.moveToThread(workerThread)
```

Currently I am facing the exact opposite problem. I have a `QObject()` instantiated in a (non-main) `QThread`. I want to move it to the main thread, like this:

```
    # Move a QObject() to the main thread
    # ------------------------------------
    # Note: these codelines execute in some QThread
    myObj = QObject()
    myObj.moveToThread(threading.main_thread())
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: moveToThread(self, QThread): argument 1 has unexpected type '_MainThread'

I probably get the error because the main thread is not a genuine `QThread`. What should I do to make it work?

---

**EDIT:**
Apparently the answer was right [in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) of the `moveToThread()` function. This is pretty embarrassing. My sincere apologies. I'll be more careful next time.

---

Comment: Why is "use QThread" not the obvious answer?

Comment: What do  you mean @ekhumoro?

Comment: Well, sorry to RTFM, but: [docs for moveToThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread).

Comment: @K.Mulier As indicated by ekhumoro the answer is in the documentation, it is very clear and I do not understand why you do not check it: `myObj.moveToThread(QApplication.instance().thread())`

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro and ellyanesc, you're right. I'm sorry. I searched on google and couldn't find examples of moving a QObject to the main thread. I forgot to look first at the moveToThread() docs. Pretty embarrassing. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QObject` instances can be created in any thread, of course. And they are, and Qt would be quite useless without it. What you're looking for is the global application object - and its thread:

```
myObj = QObject()
mainThread = QCoreApplication.instance().thread()
myObj.moveToThread(mainThread)
```

It is undefined behavior to call, from the current thread, any non-thread-safe methods on the object after the `moveToThread` call. Past this call, the object's non-thread-safe methods can be safely used from the target thread only.